# Can't email a link copied from Facebook

Tags: facebook, links, url, url-shortening

When I paste a very long URL to a Facebook group, it is no longer displayed in full. For example, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/abskal271_N782HsnaksLK (link is made up) becomes https://drive.google.com/.../abskal271_N782H... I can still use the link if I hit on it, but I can no longer copy and paste it in a browser or email. Is this a general problem and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They shorten long URLs, you have nothing to do about that.

To copy the link, just right click it and choose `Copy link address` - you can right click the textual link, or the preview.